# Can't convert to type System.IConvertible

Tags: c#, combobox, converters

I have a problem when trying to set the DataSource for a combobox. I get the error Can't converte to type System.IConvertible. It says that its because i have a System.Convert.ToInt32(object value) but i am converting the object to an int. I just can't seem to figure out how to solve this.

the data source have to fire when i select a item in another combobox.
Here is the SelectIndex event where i try to convert the objects and where i try to populate the combobox.

```
private void cbBookedSeatMovTime_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReferenceMovieRunTime.MovieRunTimeServiceClient movRunService = new ServiceReferenceMovieRunTime.MovieRunTimeServiceClient();
        ServiceReferenceSeats.SeatsServiceClient seatService = new ServiceReferenceSeats.SeatsServiceClient();

        string _selectedMovName = Convert.ToString(cbBookedSeatMovInfo.SelectedValue);
        string _selectedMovDate = Convert.ToString(cbBookedSeatMovDate.SelectedValue);
        string _selectedMovTime = Convert.ToString(cbBookedSeatMovTime.SelectedValue);

        int _runTimeId = Convert.ToInt32(movRunService.GetRunTimeOnNameDateAndTime(_selectedMovName, _selectedMovDate, _selectedMovTime));


        cbRow1.DataSource = seatService.GetRowsOnRunTime(_runTimeId);
        cbRow1.ValueMember = "id";
        cbRow1.DisplayMember = "rowId";

    }
```

To get the seatService.GetRowsOnRunTime(); i have to put in a int. And that int i get from three other comboboxes and put into the service movieRunService.GetRunTimeOnNameDateAndTime() and this needs three strings cbBookedSeatMovInfo.SelectedValue, cbBookedSeatMovDate.SelectedValue and cbBookedSeatMovTime.SelectedValue.

i dont understand why i cannot convert the object in to a int32 ? can any of you help me.

Thanks !

Comment: ...what GetRunTimeOnNameDateAndTime returns?

Comment: GetRunTimeOnNameDateAndTime returns a list of MovieRunTime.

Comment: Then how list can be converted to an integer with Convert.ToInt32()?

Comment: I dont know if this is the right way to do it ? can you suggest another way ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to convert a list of MovieRunTime in integer.

You must obtain the first element in your list and then get the integer value you need.

```
    string _selectedMovName = Convert.ToString(cbBookedSeatMovInfo.SelectedValue);
    string _selectedMovDate = Convert.ToString(cbBookedSeatMovDate.SelectedValue);
    string _selectedMovTime = Convert.ToString(cbBookedSeatMovTime.SelectedValue);

    //declare list of MovieRunTime and store your results 

    list<MovieRunTime> myList= movRunService.GetRunTimeOnNameDateAndTime(_selectedMovName, _selectedMovDate, _selectedMovTime);

   //check if your list is not null and if has items

   if (myLista != null && myLista.count > 0) {
   {

    MovieRunTime firstElement = myList[0];

    int _runTimeId = firstElement.IdValue;

    cbRow1.DataSource = seatService.GetRowsOnRunTime(_runTimeId);
    cbRow1.ValueMember = "id";
    cbRow1.DisplayMember = "rowId";

   }
```

Comment: Dont know how to declare the list of MovieRunTime ? can do it the way you show in the answer. Do i need to declare this list in my WCF service ?

Comment: For some reason i can't make a list<> of the type MovieRunTime. But the rest makes good sense! What type should i make my list ?